# Not able to send GET within a GET

Tags: c#, rest, windows-services

Im trying to build a REST proxy as windows service. But every time my program executes a GET I receive "405 method not allowed"

Structure:

1. Code1 --GET--> Code2
2. Browser --GET--> Code1 --GET--> Code2

In the first case my code just makes a GET call to another REST server. Everything works fine.

In the second case I make a GET call from my browser to the first client and it will work as a proxy, redirecting the GET call to the second client. This doesnt work. POSTs are working, only the GET does not work.

I tried different URL paths and other URL structures.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace RUST_Console_Write
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService // <-- interface of second REST client
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Test1/{s}")]
        string Test1(string s);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        string EchoWithPost(string s);
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMITM_Service
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GET1?s={s}")]
        string EchoGet1(string s);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        string EchoWithPost(string s);
    }

    public class REST_CALLS
    {
        public static string makeGET(string s)
        {
            string messageResponse = "Response from other REST Service:\n";

            try
            {
                using (ChannelFactory<IService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8001"))
                {
                    channelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
                    IService channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

                    Console.Write("Sending the GET... ");
                    messageResponse += channel.Test1(s);
                    Console.WriteLine("Success");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            return messageResponse;
        }

        public static string makePOST(string s)
        {
            string messageResponse = "Response from other REST Service:\n";

            try
            {
                using (ChannelFactory<IService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(new WebHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8001"))
                {
                    channelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
                    IService channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

                    Console.Write("Sending the POST... ");
                    messageResponse += channel.EchoWithPost(s);
                    Console.WriteLine("Success");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            return messageResponse;
        }
    }

    public class MITM_Service : IMITM_Service
    {
        public string EchoGet1(string s)
        { 
            return REST_CALLS.makeGET(s); // <---- this one fails (405)
        }

        public string EchoWithPost(string s)
        {
            return REST_CALLS.makePOST(s); // <---- this one works fine
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MITM_Service), new Uri("http://localhost:8000"));
            ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMITM_Service), new WebHttpBinding(), string.Empty);
            host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("First call");
            Console.WriteLine(REST_CALLS.makeGET("TEST")); // <---- this one works fine

            Console.WriteLine("\nSecond call");
            Console.WriteLine(REST_CALLS.makePOST("TEST")); // <---- this one works fine

            Console.ReadLine();

            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Id really appreciate every help. Cant figure it out for my life.

(I know this isnt yet a windows service, the error is the same and its better to debug as normal program)